# How can I recreate folder on each download?

Tags: python, wget, shutil, python-os

I want to do the following if the folder doesn't exist then create it, but if I execute my script (second time) obviously will be already so I need to remove the folder and download the file inside, but my current script overwrites the location, and `demo` becomes a file, how can I do this?

```
import os, shutil, wget

base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
directory = os.path.join(base_path, 'demo')
# check for extraction directories existence
if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
else:
    if os.path.exists(directory) and os.path.isdir(directory):
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
    #os.makedirs(directory)

remote_location = 'https://github.com/facebookresearch/SING/blob/master/sing/nsynth/examples.json.gz?raw=true'
try:
    wget.download(remote_location, out=directory)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Checking if a directory exists, then trying to create it if it does not, creates a race condition: some other process could create it *after* `isdir` returns `False`, but before you call `makdirs`. A better approach is to call `makedirs`, but ignore the exception raised if it already exists.

Comment: Added how to download abd also how to read it to json

Answer (score 2):

Use `pathlib` when working with path and folders

```py
from pathlib import Path
import requests

DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / "demo"

# create dir_path if it does not exist
Path(DIR_PATH).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

URL = "https://github.com/facebookresearch/SING/blob/master/sing/nsynth/examples.json.gz?raw=true"

response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
with open(f"{DIR_PATH}/example.json.gz", "wb") as h:
    for data in response.iter_content():
        h.write(data)
```

#### Explanation:

`Path(__file__).parent` returns directory (parent) to which the python script is called. With `pathlib` `/` is used to as you would in linux. We add "demo" and created it if it does not exist.

Using requests, we get the file and place it to our folder using streaming.

To read the file, we will unzip it and load it to json

```py
import json
import gzip
from pathlib import Path


DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / "demo"
with gzip.open(f"{DIR_PATH}/example.json.gz", 'rb') as gz:
    json_data = json.load(gz)
```

Comment: what about if I use `wget.download` it will remove automatically on each download?

Comment: Use `requests` or other https libraries. See updates

Answer (score -1):

```
file_name = "new_file.ext" # Needs A file name!
# Otherwise we'll just overwrite the directory
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory) # Create folder if it doesn't exist

file_location = os.path.join(directory, file_name) # Create the actual file location from our file name
remote_location = 'https://github.com/facebookresearch/SING/blob/master/sing/nsynth/examples.json.gz?raw=true'
try:
    wget.download(remote_location, out=file_location)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Don't check if the directory exists; *try* to create it, and ignore the exception raised if it already does.

Comment: The value of checking if it exists first would be to allow for some type of naming incrementation on directory name or even a chance to cancel the download. However in most cases I agree

Comment: this is exactly I have. I want to create if not exist > download, and if exist folder/file , remove with shutil.rmtree(path) , and recreate again